# Loading up a Highscore Using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

It seems when I try to load up my highscore it is making up numbers. It usually works the first time but when I load it up the number the second time it seems like it puts in numbers. Some of them are double and some are about the same as the first time.

Loading Method

```
let SecondDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var highscore = SecondDefaults.objectForKey("Highscore")?.integerValue ?? 0
    SecondDefaults.synchronize()
    Highscore = highscore

    let ThirdDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var highscore2 = ThirdDefaults.objectForKey("Highscore2")?.integerValue ?? 0
    ThirdDefaults.synchronize()
    Highscore2 = highscore2

    let FourthDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var highscore3 = FourthDefaults.objectForKey("Highscore3")?.integerValue ?? 0
    FourthDefaults.synchronize()
    Highscore3 = highscore3

    let FifthDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var highscore4 = FifthDefaults.objectForKey("Highscore4")?.integerValue ?? 0
    FifthDefaults.synchronize()
    Highscore4 = highscore4

    let SixthDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var highscore5 = SixthDefaults.objectForKey("Highscore5")?.integerValue ?? 0
    SixthDefaults.synchronize()
    Highscore5 = highscore5
```

Here is my saving method if that helps.

```
if Score > Highscore {

    Highscore5 = Highscore4
    let SixthDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    SixthDefaults.setObject(Highscore5, forKey: "Highscore5")
    SixthDefaults.synchronize()
    Highscore5String = String(Highscore5)
    FifthHighscoreLabel.text = Highscore5String

    Highscore4 = Highscore3
    let FifthDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    FifthDefaults.setObject(Highscore4, forKey: "Highscore4")
    FifthDefaults.synchronize()
    Highscore4String = String(Highscore4)
    FourthHighscoreLabel.text = Highscore4String

    Highscore3 = Highscore2
    let FourthDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    FourthDefaults.setObject(Highscore3, forKey: "Highscore3")
    FourthDefaults.synchronize()
    Highscore3String = String(Highscore3)
    ThirdHighscoreLabel.text = Highscore3String

    Highscore2 = Highscore
    let ThirdDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    ThirdDefaults.setObject(Highscore2, forKey: "Highscore2")
    ThirdDefaults.synchronize()
    Highscore2String = String(Highscore2)
    SecondHighscoreLabel.text = Highscore2String

        Highscore = Score
        let SecondDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        SecondDefaults.setObject(Highscore, forKey: "Highscore")
        SecondDefaults.synchronize()
        HighscoreString = String(Highscore)
        HighscoreLabel.text = HighscoreString

    HighscoreString = String(Highscore)
    HighscoreLabel.text = HighscoreString
    Highscore2String = String(Highscore2)
    SecondHighscoreLabel.text = Highscore2String
    Highscore3String = String(Highscore3)
    ThirdHighscoreLabel.text = Highscore3String
    Highscore4String = String(Highscore4)
    FourthHighscoreLabel.text = Highscore4String
    Highscore5String = String(Highscore5)
    FifthHighscoreLabel.text = Highscore5String


    }
else {
    HighscoreString = String(Highscore)
    HighscoreLabel.text = HighscoreString
    Highscore2String = String(Highscore2)
    SecondHighscoreLabel.text = Highscore2String
    Highscore3String = String(Highscore3)
    ThirdHighscoreLabel.text = Highscore3String
    Highscore4String = String(Highscore4)
    FourthHighscoreLabel.text = Highscore4String
    Highscore5String = String(Highscore5)
    FifthHighscoreLabel.text = Highscore5String        }
```

Comment: You don't need to create another NSUserDefaults object for every highscore you add, you can just reuse your first object. If you read  a value you don't have to synchronize (no changes have to be written to disk).

Comment: That doesn't really help solve my problem though.

Comment: no, but it can reduce your code to 5/6 lines each which is easier to debug. I am also not sure if it wont fix your bug.